# boundedness of norm of convolution 2

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $1\le p\le \infty$, $f\in L^1(R)$, and $g\in L^p(R)$.
Show that $(f*g)(x)=\int_R f(x-y)g(y)\,dy$ exists for almost all x, that $f*g\in L^p(R)$, and that $\|f*g\|_p\le\|f\|_1 \|g\|_p$.

So this is from Rudin's RCA 3rd edition chapter 8.

And in the previous question, I thought I solved for $1<p<\infty$ case, but I was wrong.

What I have tried is
$$\int\left(\int f(x-y)g(y)\,dy\right)^p\,dx\le\|f\|_1^{p/q}\int\int|f(x-y)|g(y)|^p\,dy\,dx \tag 1$$
since $$\int f(x-y)g(y)\,dy\le\|f\|_1^{1/q}\left(\int|f(x-y)||g(y)|^p\,dy\right)^{1/p}\tag 2$$
But to get (1) from (2) requires, left side of (2) is biggers than 1, which I cannot tell it is under given condition. So how can I show this inequality?

My guess is to use Holder and Minkowski for integral. But I don't know how to use it properly.

Additional question : How can I show that I can apply Fubini's Theorem, that is how can I show that the integral of x-section of $F(x,y)=f(x-y)g(y)$ is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\in\left[1,\infty\right)$ and let $p'=p/\left(p-1\right)$ his Holder conjugate. We have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\left(x-y\right)g\left(y\right)dy\right|\right)^{p}dx\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)g\left(y\right)\right|dy\right)^{p}dx=$$
 $$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|^{1/p}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|^{1/p'}\left|g\left(y\right)\right|dy\right)^{p}dx\leq$$ $$\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|dy\right)^{p/p'}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|\left|g\left(y\right)\right|^{p}dy\right)dx$$
 for the Holder inequality. Now we make a change of value and we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|dy\right)^{p/p'}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|\left|g\left(y\right)\right|^{p}dy\right)dx=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(y\right)\right|dy\right)^{p-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|\left|g\left(y\right)\right|^{p}dy=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{1}^{p-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|g\left(y\right)\right|^{p}dy=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{1}^{p-1}\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{1}\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{p}^{p}=$$ $$
 =\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{1}^{p}\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{p}^{p}<\infty.$$
 If $p=\infty$ you have $$\left|f*g\left(x\right)\right|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)g\left(y\right)\right|dy\leq\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\left(x-y\right)\right|dy=\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{\infty}\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{1}.$$